# Single with flowable?

Tags: kotlin, rx-java2

Try in rxJava2 Kotlin combine Single with Flowable but nothing not happening:
Does not undrstand what wrong

```
  Flowable.create<Int>({ emmit ->

            loadNewListener = object :Listener {
                override fun onEmit(id: Int) {
                    emmit.onNext(id)
                }
            }
        }, BackpressureStrategy.LATEST)
                .debounce(500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                .flatMapSingle {
                    loadNew(id = it.id)
                }
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe({ (data:Data) ->

                }, {

                    Timber.e("Failed load data ${it.message}")
                })
```

my method is returning Single:

```
private fun loadNew(id: Int): Single<Data> {

            return when (pdfType) {

                CASE_0 -> {

                    Single.create<Data> { emmit ->

             service.get("data")
                    .enqueue(
                    object : Callback<Void> {
                         override fun onFailure(call: Call<Void>?, t: Throwable?) {
                            // failure
                        }

                          override fun onResponse(call: Call<Void>?, response:  Response<Void>?) {
                 emmit.onSuccess(it.data)
            }
                        }
                    }//single
                }//case_0


                CASE_1 -> 1Repository.loadsome1Rx(id = id).map { it.getData() }

                CASE_2 -> 2Repository.loadsom2LocalRx(id = id).map { it.getData() }

                else -> {
                    throw java.lang.RuntimeException("$this is not available type!")
                }
            }
```

What is wrong im my code?
Need Maby call Single in Flowable subscribe() seppurate
like this?

```
Flowable.create<Int>({ emmit ->
        loadNewListener = object :Listener {
            override fun onEmit(id: Int) {
                emmit.onNext(id)
            }
        }
    }, BackpressureStrategy.LATEST)
            .debounce(500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)

          .subscribe({
              loadNew(id = it.id)

          }, {
              Timber.e("")
          })
```

This code is workin but looks not simple as via combine try.

Comment: Where do you use loadNewListener?

Comment: @Tuby for emits user clicks, but if i click rxJava not calling

Comment: Looks ok to me, maybe you call id=0 and there is failure during service.get("data").

Comment: @Tuby no failed because. Other variant without combine single and flowable is full working

Comment: Can you strip your sample code down to a smaller version that exhibits the behavior? Currently, I am getting lost in the excess of details.

Comment: @Tuby ypu are right the problem was in loadNewListener. He did not  init in time and was null when need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Stas Bondar said in [answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54323134/6352712) This simple example based on your code is working!!

Problem was in loadNewListener .

It does not init in time and has null value when need. Call create Flowable on init ViewModel but loadNewListener did not have time to create when i call him from fragment.

> loadNewListener = object :Listener{...}

Becuse need some time mutch for init rxJava expression!

And combine flowable with single via flatMapSingle spent more time than just call single on flowable dubscrinbe!

So use temp field:

```
     private var temp: Temp? = null

        fun load(id: Int) {

 loadNewListener.apply {

                when {
                    this != null -> load(id = id)

                    else -> userEmitPdfTemp = Temp(id = id)
                }
            }
        }




 Flowable.create<Data>({ emmit ->

                    userEmitPdfTemp?.let {id->

                        emmit.onNext(Data(id))
                        userEmitPdfTemp =null

                    }

                    loadNewListener = object :Listener {
                        override fun load(id: Int) {

                            emmit.onNext(Data(id))

                        }
                    }

                }
```

Answer (score 1):

This simple example based on your code is working

```
var i = 0
fun foo() {
    Flowable.create<Int>({ emmit ->
        emmit.onNext(i)
        i++
    }, BackpressureStrategy.LATEST)
            .debounce(500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .flatMapSingle {
                Single.create<String> { emmit ->
                    emmit.onSuccess("onSuccess: $it")
                }
            }
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe({
                Log.i("RX", "Subscribe: $it")
            }, {
                it.printStackTrace()
            })
}
```

Check `SingleEmitter.onSuccess()` and `SingleEmitter.onError()` is called in all cases in `when (pdfType)...`

Comment: You are right that code is workig. Problem was in loadNewListener. He does not became init in time and has null value when need.